# How to improve performance in "like '%variable%'"?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, indexing

I have this query in MySQL:

```
select *
from alias where
name like '%jandro%';
```

Which results are:

```
Jandro, Alejandro
```

The index on name cannot be applied to higher performance because it is a range filter. **Is there any way of improving that query performance?**

I have tried with a **full-text index**, but it only works for complete words.

I also tried with a **MEMORY ENGINE** table, and it is faster, but I would like a better choice.

**EDIT** 
I think i will have just to accept this for now:

```
select *
from alias where match(name) against ('jandro*' in boolean mode);
```

Comment: A 'MEMORY ENGINE' is faster because the whole table exists (only) in RAM. If you shutdown your database server or computer, the table is GONE. This might be fine if you have the table somewhere else (another table, non-memory) somewhere, but do know your data is not persistent!

Comment: Thanks. I know that. It was only a denormalized table in memory for faster lookups! :-)

Comment: Ok sorry, good that you know, but I'll leave the comment so the next person that comes looking for a solution doesn't use the 'MAGICAL MEMORY ENGINE' and thinks his problems are solved ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in the past (not on MySQL, and before full text searching was commonly available on database servers) by creating a lookup table, in which I created all left-chopping substrings to search on.

In my case, it was merited - a key user journey involved searching for names in much the way you suggest, and performance was key.

It worked with triggers on insert, update and delete.

Translated to your example:

Table alias

```
ID          name
1           Jandro
2           Alejandro
```

Table name_lookup

```
alias_id          name_substring
1                 Jandro
1                 andro
1                 ndro
1                 dro
1                 ro
2                 Alejandro
2                 lejandro
2                 ejandro
2                 jandro
2                 andro
2                 ndro
2                 dro
2                 ro
```

Your query then becomes

```
select alias_id, name
from alias a, 
     name_lookup nl
where a.id = ni.alias_id
and   ni.name_substring like 'andro%'
```

That way, you hit the index on the name_substring table.

It's only worth doing for common queries on huge data sets - but it works, and it's quick.